# How to change the Order Reference to Number Reference

Tags: prestashop

Using new version of Prestashop 1.5.2.0. I would like to change the Order reference ( alphabets ) to alphanumeric value. I tried searching in forums and Seen this forum. Unfortunately it wont work for me.

Can any one have solution to change Order reference ( alphabets ) to alphanumeric value in entire application.

I mean "AQMKATRQG" to "LD1001" and the increment it to "LD1002" I would like to change the Order reference ( alphabets ) to alphanumeric value. I tried searching in forums and Seen this forum. Unfortunately it wont work for me.

Can any one have solution to change Order reference ( alphabets ) to alphanumeric value in entire application.

I mean "AQMKATRQG" to "LD1001" and the increment it to "LD1002"

Answer (score 16):

In PrestaShop 1.6 (tested and confirmed working in v1.6.0.14) you can accomplish this by the following method.

1. *Copy* the file `/classes/PaymentModule.php` to `/override/classes/PaymentModule.php`.
2. *Edit* the file `/override/classes/PaymentModule.php` as follows.

At lines 337-341 is a code block that should read like this:

```
if (!result)
{
  PrestaShopLogger::addLog('PaymentModule::validateOrder - Order cannot be created',
    3, null, 'Cart', (int)$id_cart, true);
  throw new PrestaShopException('Can\'t save Order');
}
```

Immediately after that code block, insert the following two lines of code:

```
$order->reference = str_pad($order->id, 9, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$order->update();
```

3. *Delete* the file `/cache/class_index.php` so that Prestashop automatically re-creates this file taking into account the new override file.
4. Any existing records in your PrestaShop database can be updated to use a numerical reference manually using a tool such as [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/).

I would imagine the steps would be very similar if not identical to these for PrestaShop v1.5 but at this time I have not tested this solution with PrestaShop v1.5. If someone finds this solution works on v1.5 perhaps they could confirm this in the comments. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The above solutions are essentially correct, but you REALLY should refrain from modifying any of the core code if you can keep from it. I put all of my mods in a special folder locally after I apply any upgrades to prestashop or my theme engine, then I upload the modifications one by one (after each one is tested).

These instructions are for 1.6.x users - but MAY work on 1.5.x - I don't have that code to test with.

1) Create a file named order.php and place the code below in that file

2) Next, upload the file to /override/classes/order/order.php

3) Navigate to the /cache folder and delete the file class_index.php (it will be recreated on the next page request)

```
<?php
/*
 *  RETURN ORDER REFERENCE TO SEQUENTIAL NUMERIC VALUE
 *
 *  2016 PrestaShop v1.6.1.x
 *  Override by obewanz
 *
 *  You can use the following SQL query to change the starting order no if desired
 *  where the number 101 is the next desired order number:
 *  ALTER TABLE `ps_orders` AUTO_INCREMENT = 101
 *  --------------------------------------------
 *  OPTION: (ALL NUMERIC)
 *  str_pad((int)$last_id + 1, 9, '000000000', STR_PAD_LEFT);
 *  OPTION SET TO ORIG 1.5.x STYLE REFERENCE NUMBERS: 
 *  str_pad((int)$last_id + 1, 6, '000000', STR_PAD_LEFT);
 */

Class Order extends OrderCore {
  public static function generateReference() {
    $last_id = Db::getInstance()->getValue('SELECT MAX(id_order)
                                            FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'orders');
    return str_pad((int)$last_id + 1, 9, 'NR-000000', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  }
}
```

You should be finished now, and your next order will have a reference something like: NR-000101

The second "OPTION" in the code comments returns the order reference number to essentially that of PS 1.5.x - (I had a reference to it in an old file.)

I have also included the appropriate SQL statement in the code comments to set the next order number if needed.