# Wrong order number in prestashop pdf invoice

Tags: pdf, prestashop, tcpdf

I am trying to put the order id in the footer of the prestashop PDF invoice.
For this I added this in the file /theme/mytheme/pdf/footer.tpl:

```
{assign var="orderId" value="%05d"|sprintf:$order->id}
{$orderId}
```

However, when I go to orders > invoices and I generate a PDF, when there are more than one order, the last page of the PDF has the order id of the previous invoice... All the others are ok except for this one.

Did I do something wrong or is it a prestashop or a tcpdf bug ?

**UPDATE**

A user on the prestashop forum suggested to assign the order variable to smarty in the getFooter() function of /classes/pdf/HTMLTemplate.php.
I did and now, on all the  pages I have the order id of the next page, except for the last one which has the right one...

Comment: In case it helps, if what you're really trying to accomplish is to use the Order number instead of the reference, then see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897408/how-to-change-the-order-reference-to-number-reference