# Prestashop 1.6 Order Number sequence reset per time period

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop-1.6, sequences

### SYNOPSIS

I am running my eCommerce shop using Prestashop 1.6.  I have already reconfigured my Order Numbers to the format `SO/2018/000001` based on `ps_orders.ps_id_order` using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30053257/2464491) as a guide. Updating `override/classes/PaymentModule.php` with this block:

```
$oNum = str_pad($order->id, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$oYear = substr(date(Y),0,4);
$order->reference = "SO/$oYear/$oNum";
$order->update();
```

I then used the following query to update set determine the next `id_order`:

```
ALTER TABLE ps_orders AUTO_INCREMENT = 10
```

This made my `reference` longer than the defined field, so I also had to adjust the definition in `/override/class/Order.php`:

```
'reference' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'size' => 14),
```

And in `/override/class/OrderPayment.php`:

```
'order_reference' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isAnything', 'size' => 14),
```

With all that done, my order numbers were formatted the way I wanted, but are not exactly as desired.

### DESIRED RESULT

Rather than using the `ps_orders` table's key index field as the basis of my order numbers, I would like to use a separate sequence which resets each year.  Similar to how the `OrderInvoiceCore` class uses the `number` field to generate the actual invoice number based on the `Invoice Options` set in the back office.

### PLEASE ADVISE

What is the best way to go about achieving this desired result?  I am thinking that adding a sequence to the `OrderCore` class, and using that to generate my order reference numbers in place of `ps_orders.id_order` would do the trick.  If that is the best solution in my case, how do I go about implementing such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the number of orders in current year and add one to it, when generating the reference.

```
$nextid = (int)Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS("SELECT count(`id_order`) FROM `"._DB_PREFIX_."orders` WHERE `date_add` > '".date('Y')."-01-01'") + 1;
```

I would do it by overriding the add function in Order class to something like:

```
public function add($autodate = true, $null_values = true)
{
    $nextid = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS("SELECT count(`id_order`) FROM `__DB_PREFIX__orders` WHERE `date_add` > '".date('Y')."-01-01'") + 1;
    $this->reference = "SO/".date('Y')."/".str_pad($nextid, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

    parent::add($autodate, $null_values);
}
```

Comment: For some reason, when apply this solution, even though I already have 2018 orders, adding a new order produces `SO/2018/000001`, rather than the number of orders this year plus one.  Now, every order is being assigned `SO/2018/000001`.

Comment: @SirachMatthews I had the wrong constant for the db prefix. Now it's working (I've tested myself).

Comment: Ok.  That worked.  Although, I opted to place the variable definition in my `PaymentModule` override class rather than the `add` function of the `Order` class.  Thank you greatly for the assist!